# Flyway:Environment Placeholder is not recognizing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway

Have downloaded the flyway version flyway-7.14.0 command-line tar file in MAC

Unable to read the value from the FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_RETSCHEMA, tried with both $ and @

I have given in the script as below

```
export FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_RETSCHEMA=DEV_RET
/path/flyway/flyway-7.14.0/flyway migrate -configFiles=config/flyway_dev.conf -password='****'
```

The V1.0.0__init.sql file is as below

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS @{RETSSCHEMA};
USE SCHEMA @{RETSCHEMA};
```

But it threw an error

```
Successfully validated 51 migrations (execution time 00:19.616s)
Current version of schema "DEV_RET": << Empty Schema >>
Migrating schema "DEV_RET" to version "1.0.0 - init"
ERROR: Migration of schema "DEV_RET" to version "1.0.0 - init" failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
ERROR: Migration V1.0.0__init.sql failed
---------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 1003
Message    : SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 28 unexpected '@{RETSCHEMA}'.
Location   : sql/flyway/versions/V1.0.0__init.sql (/Users/work/sql/flyway/versions/V1.0.0__init.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS @{RETSCHEMA}
```

Comment: Is this issue related to Snowflake or any of it's drivers?

Comment: looks like a typo: in you variable it's named export RETSCHEMA and in your file RETSSCHEMA